# Forward call to Action class when validation fails

Tags: struts, struts-validation

I'm working on struts 1.1 application.
 I have added validation for JSP form page(i.e. adduser.jsp).
It get validated after clicking on add button. And my validation in "Validator-XSS.xml" working fine.
But when validation fails then it forward to input attribute which is jsp form page(i.e. adduser.jsp).
Here I need to forward callto another action 
 (i. e.openAddUser.do)
which open JSP form page(i.e. adduser.jsp) insted of JSP page.

**UPDATE**

struts-config.xml

```
    <struts-config>
    <!-- some another entries -->

    <form-bean name="UserForm" type="com.UserForm"/>

    <action path="/createuser" type="com.CreateUserAction" name="UserForm" 
    scope="request"> 
            <forward name="adduser" path="/jsp/adduser.jsp"/> 
    </action>

    <action path="/adduser" type="com.AddUserAction" input="/jsp/adduser.jsp" 
name="UserForm" scope="request"> 
            <forward name="showuser" path="/showUserDetails.do"/>
    </action>

    <plug-in className="org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn">
        <set-property
            property="pathnames"
            value="/WEB-INF/User-Validator.xml"/>
    </plug-in>
    </struts-config>
```

XSS-validator.xml

```
<form-validation>
<formset>
    <form name="UserForm">

        <field property="userName" depends="mask">
<msg name="mask" key="ui.field.invalidvalue" bundle="appResources"/>                
            <var>
                <var-name>mask</var-name>
                <var-value>^[a-zA-Z0-9-_]*$</var-value>
            </var>
        </field>

    </form>
</formset>
```

on clicking on create user in jsp file it will call **createuser.do** It will open adduser.jsp
after entering details in form and click on add button it will **adduser.do** 
also it get vlidated through XSS-validator.xml
but call goes to **jsp/adduser.jsp** but i need it has to call **createuser.do**

```
ActionForm is extended by ValidatorForm



public class UserForm extends ValidatorForm{

    String userName;
    String userId;

    //getter setter
    }

ActionClass



Public Class CreateUserAction{
    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping,ActionForm form,HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {

    //some code to bring list and other details

    mapping.findForward("adduser");
    }

    Public Class AddUserAction{
    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping,ActionForm form,HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {

   //some code to add user and other details

    mapping.findForward("showuser");
    }
```

Comment: And what happens if you change the input attribute to `/openAddUser.do`?

Comment: @JBNizet : Giving Exception "HTTP Status 500 - No input attribute for mapping path /openAddUser.do"

Comment: That seems to indicate that the action mapped to openAddUser.do also tries to validate, and to forward to its own input attribute, which doesn't exist.

Comment: @JBNizet: what would be the solution then...

Comment: Show your code, show your struts-config.xml. I personally would avoid struts validator completely, and even avoid struts completely, in fact.

Comment: @JBNizet: please check update and suggest me..

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are not calling that action with the path. try this use this way to call that method that will work and will solve you problem.

Call Method and action

That will work accordingly. to call that action.